# Writing items in Python dictionary as individual objects with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I'm working with a short python script that is designed to do the following:

1. Read multiple text files
2. Tokenize each text file into sentences (using NLTK)
3. Construct a dictionary where the keys are sentences and the values are the files within which the sentences can be found.
4. Write the python dictionary to mongodb

The script is broadly successful against these four objectives, however, I'm not storing the data correctly.

All of the sentences and filenames are being stored in a single `objectID` on mongodb, e.g.:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59106ca29fb5ba4b182e9534"),
"Long opinions were given in the Court of Session on the question of fraud but the alternative case of a duty to disclose was dealt with summarily" : [ 
    "test.txt"
],
"If liability is imposed on the council, it would tend, I think, to make them do their work better, rather than worse" : [ 
    "test2.txt"
]
...
```

What I'm really looking to do is store each sentence (the key) and source files (then values) as its own object, e.g.:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59106ca29fb5ba4b182e9534"),
"Long opinions were given in the Court of Session on the question of fraud but the alternative case of a duty to disclose was dealt with summarily" : [ 
    "test.txt"
]
}

{
       "_id" : ObjectId("84384389382483948392"),
        "If liability is imposed on the council, it would tend, I think, to make them do their work better, rather than worse" : [ 
            "test2.txt"
        ]
}
```

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
d = {}

# Read the source file

directory = '/Users/dh/Documents/Development/Python/regex'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    if filename.endswith('.txt'):

        source = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')
        content = source.read()
        name = source.name

# Tokenise the source file into sentences

        tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
        sents = tokenizer.tokenize(content)

# Clean the list because mongo doesn't like fullpoints in the key

        clean_sents = map(lambda each:each.strip(u'.'),sents)
        cleaner_sents = [word.replace('.', '') for word in clean_sents]

        print cleaner_sents
        print d

        # Populate the empty dictionary with the sentences as keys and the filename as a value

        for i in cleaner_sents:
            d.setdefault(i, []).append(name)



print json.dumps(d.items(), sort_keys=True, indent=4) # output the dictionary as prettified json

# Write the dictionary to mongo

sentence_matrix = d
sentences = db.sentences
sentence_id = sentences.insert_one(sentence_matrix).inserted_id
pprint.pprint(sentences.find_one())
```

I'm very new to MongoDB. I've consulted the PyMongo documentation (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) but am drawing a blank.

**Update**

I thought I'd try iterating over the dictionary with a `for` loop as follows:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():

    sentence_matrix = d
    sentences = db.sentences
    sentence_id = sentences.insert_one(sentence_matrix).inserted_id
    pprint.pprint(sentences.find_one())
```

But that results in the following error:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    sentence_id = db.sentences.insert_one({'sentence': key, 'file': value})
```

Or for fewer round-trips to the server:

```
db.sentences.insert_many([
    {'sentence': key, 'file': value}
    for key, value in d.iteritems()])
```

Comment: Excellent, I ended up going for your first suggestion but may revert to the second when I get round to cleaning the code up a bit. Many thanks.